# CSS3 Hover Animation not responding

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to get figcaption caption to appear fade in/animate on hover on the bottom. But i cannot get the figcaption div tag seems to disappear off the screen.

I want it so that when you hover over the banner, the figcaption appears regardless over where the mouse is hovering over.

i have 4 elements:
- the background image
- gradient overlay
- description
- figcaption

```
the current code i have is: http://jsfiddle.net/fGF8E/
```

Comment: your fiddle is not showing the image, there is a error in console, check it out

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fGF8E/1/ im just using a image from google for demonstration purposes. Neither images are working for some reason :/ the size is 900px x 350px

Comment: I think AdBlock is blocking that image for me.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/47QEM/1/) with simulated image area

Comment: [Demo]  This Is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/47QEM/2/)

```
.figcaption {
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;

    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;

    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}

.landing-cover:hover .figcaption{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
}
```

Comment: perfect! works brilliantly! quick question i've been struggling to try and get the size to remain at 350px height on different viewports and the image to centre i.e. on a small screen the left/right will be partially cut off but the image itself will remain in the center

Comment: @JT1 can you explain in brief? or provide a demo, so I can understand better.

Comment: I've created a fiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Rx6LC/ as you can see from the demo, when the screen is at a mobile view point, the image is squashed to fit the 350px box size, however i want it so that the image maintains it original aspect ratio, but rather moves to the center of the box (cutting off the left or right if needed)